# I am trying to add user input from the second form with title, description to my Data array but can't

Tags: c#, windows, forms, class

```
namespace To_Do_List_Application
{
    public partial class Create_new_task : Form
    {
        public Create_new_task()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            Data[] add_item = new Data[10];


            add_item[1] = new Data(Title_Input);
// I get the error Data does not contain constructor that takes 1 argument


        }


// Data Class on program.cs ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

public class Data
    {
        // Menu (form)
        public int Priority;
        public string Title;
        public string Description;


        // Create new task (form)
        public DateTime Calender;
        public string Description_2;
        public int Tick;
        public Data(int priority, string title, string description, DateTime calender, string description_2, int tick)
        {
            // Menu (form)
            Title = title;
            Description = description;

            // Create new task (form)
            Calender = calender;
            Description_2 = description_2;
            Tick = tick;
            Priority = priority;

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you try to create new Data object you have to use your contructor which takes 6 arguments.in your case your code should look somethinglike this :

```
add_item[1] = new Data(5,"title", "description", new DateTime(2015, 4, 25), "desc2",3);
```

creating a new object happens through constructors :

public Data(int priority, string title, string description, DateTime calender, string description_2, int tick)

is your constructor and you can create a new data object only with these 6 arguments.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is because you are attempting initialize a new Data object with a single parameter when you haven't provided a signature that accepts a single argument:

```
add_item[1] = new Data(Title_Input);
```

Add an overloaded constructor to the Data class that accepts an argument that is the type of Title_Input and you shouldn't have that issue any longer.

Eg.

```
// Default constructor (This constructor is provided automatically by
// default if not explicitly defined. Including it in the class definition
// allows you to initialize the object with default parameters when creating
// a new Data object without providing any parameters.)
public Data()
{
}

// Overloaded constructor that accepts a single parameter
public Data(Title_Input input)
{
    //Do something with the parameter input
    ...
}

// Overloaded constructor that accepts 6 arguments
public Data(int priority, string title, string description, DateTime calender, string description_2, int tick)
{
    // Menu (form)
    Title = title;
    Description = description;

    // Create new task (form)
    Calender = calender;
    Description_2 = description_2;
    Tick = tick;
    Priority = priority;
    ...
 }
```